# Location of Account/ Login picture on Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra

Tags: mac, macos

I used this solution -

```
sudo dscl . -read /Users/$USER JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > ~/Desktop/$USER.jpg
```

Is there any other better way to locate the filesystem storage location for this picture?

Answer (score 2):

There is a terminal command that will print the path of the desktop picture on the picture itself. Using the terminal enter the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;killall Dock
```

Your desktop picture should now show the directory path to its location. When you get the location of the image you can turn this off by typing:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text;killall Dock
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be refined as:

```
dscl . -read ~$USER JPEGPhoto | xxd -p -r > $USER.jpg
```

Or you can access the property list with the picture directly. They are stored in `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$USER.plist`, you can extract the picture using the following commands:

```
sudo plutil -convert xml1 -o - /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$USER.plist |
    vim '+/>j/+3,/>j//<\/d/-1j | .!base64 -D > $USER.jpg' '+q!' -
```

Comment: How does any of these commands "locate the filesystem storage location" of the user picture as asked in the question?

Comment: The plist is a file and the user’s picture is encoded in it.